Cost function lagrangian equality penalty in QAOA
I try to apply the QAOA to a given problem composed of $x_1,\dots,x_n$ boolean (0/1).
Each variable $x_i$ is then encoded on one qubit.
There is the constraint on theses variables that :
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1
\end{equation}
that is to say only one boolean at a time is non zero.
In the sequel, $x$ is the vector $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$.
My problem has a cost function $C(x)$ which I want to minimize. To account for the given constraint, I penalize my cost function with the lagrangian function :
\begin{equation}
L(x) = 1 - \sum_{i=1}^n x_i + 2\sum_{i<j} x_i x_j
\end{equation}
you can check that $L(x)=0$ only if previous constraint is satisfied, and $L(x)>0$ otherwise.
Then, I have a new cost function :
\begin{equation}
C^\prime (x) = C (x) + \lambda L(x)
\end{equation}
with $\lambda > 0$ the lagrangian parameter which makes all solutions not complying to the constraint less minimal than those complying to the constraints.
With QAOA, I then search for a Hamiltonian such that :
\begin{equation}
H |x\rangle = C^\prime (x) |x\rangle = C (x)|x\rangle + \lambda L(x)|x\rangle
\end{equation}
It is enough to replace all $x_i$ occurence by $\frac{1}{2}(I-Z_i)$ where
\begin{equation}
Z_i = I\otimes \dots\otimes \underbrace{Z}_{i}\otimes \dots \otimes I
\end{equation}
I focus on the Hamiltonian due to the constraint penalty $L$ :
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
H &= \lambda \biggl[ I - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n (I - Z_i) + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i<j}(I-Z_i)(I-Z_j)\biggr]\\\\
 &= \lambda \biggl[\biggl(1 + \frac{n(n-3)}{4}\biggr)I + \frac{n}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i<j}Z_i Z_j\biggr]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
There is an identity term $I$ with the constant $c=\lambda\biggl(1 + \frac{n(n-3)}{4}\biggr)$, which will only add a global phase term to all qubits upon evolution :
\begin{equation}
U(t)|x\rangle = e^{-icIt}|x\rangle = e^{-ict}|x\rangle
\end{equation}
Then, it would not be necessary to keep it, as it does not change the minimization process. But on the other hand, there is a constant coming from the constraint penalty $L(x)$ and if I do not keep it, the penalty constraint might not work.
What should I do ? How can I handle properly in QAOA this equality constraint ?
